# RecyclerView does not load image

Tags: java, android

I am using a recyclerView for a menu which has a title, description and a image. The title & description are displayed but the image is not. No error is thrown or anything though.

In my code below the imageName is the file name of the image in my res > drawable directory, i.e. revise_notepad.jpg What am I missing?

**code - XML**

**activity_main**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mark.spanishapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/esp_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**menu_layout**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menuImg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**code - Java**

**MainActivity**

```
  package com.example.mark.spanishapp;

    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.util.Log;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
        DBHandler dbHandler = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbHandler = new DBHandler(this);
        try {
            dbHandler.createDataBase();

        }catch (IOException ioe){
            throw new Error("unable to create database");
        }

        try{
            dbHandler.openDataBase();
        }catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, sqle.getMessage());
        }

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.esp_menu);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        ArrayList<MenuEsp> menuList = dbHandler.Get_MenuList();

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), menuList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

**MenuEsp**

```
  package com.example.mark.spanishapp;

    public class MenuEsp {

    public String getMenu() {
        return menu;
    }

    public void setMenu(String menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImageName() {
        return imageName;
    }

    public void setImageName(String imageName) {
        this.imageName = imageName;
    }

    private String menu;
    private String description;
    private String imageName;
}
```

**MyAdapter**

```
 package com.example.mark.spanishapp;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<MenuEsp> menuList;
    private Context context;

    public  MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MenuEsp> menuList){
        this.context = context;
        this.menuList = menuList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(menuList.get(position).getMenu());
        holder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        int id = this.context.getResources().getIdentifier(menuList.get(position).getImageName(), "drawable", this.context.getPackageName());
        holder.img.setImageResource(id);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return menuList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView title;
        private TextView descirption;
        private ImageView img;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            descirption = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.description);
            title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.menuImg);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: print `id` (onBindViewHolder) to Logcat and see what you get.

Comment: just check what you are getting in menuList.get(position).getImageName(). Is it the correct image name that you have stored in drawable folder

Comment: when i evaluate the line I get the result, revise_notepad.jpg & count = 18 & I can see revise_notepad.jpg in andriod studio under res > drawable

Comment: @MaihanNijat the id is always 0, so guessing this is my issue

Comment: @mHelpMe, give a try to picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/) may be it covers your mistake.

Comment: @mHelpMe To fix it now, make sure you are getting value from the database and then make sure `getImageName()` return values. `Log.d` will help you to debug the problem. Best of luck.

Comment: thanks for the help I found out that the name i.e revise_notepad.jpg should not contain the file extension. The images are now coming through!